# Поиск n-го слова в строке, содержащей слова, разделенные пробелами

Tags: c++, строки

Есть строка std::string, которая содержит слова, разделенные символами пробела (возможно, несколькими).

Подскажите, существует ли удобный способ, чтобы с помощью средств стандартной библиотеки найти n-е слово в строке?

Самому написать такой парсер можно, но это будет не логично, если существуют уже готовые методы.

Например: дана строка `std::string str = "adc dcrf  afds qqq";`

Хочу найти слово под номером 1. Ожидаемый ответ: `dcrf`.

Возможный вариант решения: сделать что-нибудь наподобие `split`, чтобы перевести строку в массив строк, содержащий эти слова, и затем по номеру найти элемент.

Возможно, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным.

Спасибо.

Comment: Кстати, советую главу "Строковые потоки" в книге Стенли Липпмана "С++. Базовый курс".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вот так.

По скорости это может и не оптимальный вариант, зато пишется просто.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str = "adc dcrf  afds qqq";
    int index = 2; // Номер слова.

    std::istringstream ss(str);
    auto iter = std::next(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss), index);

    if (!ss)
    {
        std::cout << "Index out of range.";
        return 0;
    }

    std::string result = *iter;
    std::cout << result << '\n'; // Печатает `afds`.
}
```

---

[Похоже](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), что до C++17 `next` работал только с forward iterator'ами, тогда как `istream_iterator` - это input iterator.

Для C++14 и более старых стандартов можно написать так:

```
auto iter = std::istream_iterator<std::string>(ss);
std::advance(iter, index);
```

Comment: Спасибо за оперативный ответ! Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы связываете поток ввода со строкой, и по ней проходите итератором?

Comment: @fedruches Угу, все так.

Comment: А не подскажете, где про это можно подробнее прочитать, кроме документации на cppreference?

Comment: @fedruches Сомневаюсь, что найдете что-то лучше, чем английский cppreference. Можно еще попробовать поискать про `istream_iterator` на английском SO.

Comment: в VS2017 получаю ошибку: "next requires forward iterator". Из istream_iterator получить forward мне не удалось)

Comment: потому что это  однонаправленный итератор для чтения

Comment: @fedruches Добавил альтерантиву.

Comment: @fedruches Если разобрались, жмякните галочку слева. На нее репутация не нужна. :) Это значит, что вашу проблему решили, и помощь вам больше не нужна.

Comment: @fedruches Может где-то настройках проекта можно заставить студию использовать последний стандарт?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я вспомнил. Когда брал проект, он был на VS13 Pro, и я поставил галку "не обновляться", то есть работаю по сути только с C++11 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string  find_string_n(const std::string& s, size_t pos)
{
    std::istringstream is(s);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> p(is);
    while (--pos) ++p;
    return *p;
}
```

Если `pos >= количеству слов`, то функция возвратит последнее слово